# How to test React Native component with NavigationEvents in jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

How can I write a jest unit test for a react native component which contains a `NavigationEvents` subcomponent.

I've tried the solutions offered in questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114589/488802) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153339/488802) without success.

The error I am getting is

```
    console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9215
      The above error occurred in the <Context.Consumer> component:
          in withNavigation(NavigationEvents) (created by MyComponent)
          in View (created by View)
          in View (created by MyComponent)
          in MyComponent

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

  ● MyComponent test › renders

    Invariant Violation: withNavigation can only be used on a view hierarchy of a navigator. The wrapped component is unable to get access to navigation from props or context.
```

Below is a minimal example that causes the error.

```
import 'react-native';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <NavigationEvents/>
          </View>
        );}
  }

describe('MyComponent test', () => {
    it('renders', () => {

        jest.mock('react-navigation', () =>({
            NavigationEvents: 'mockNavigationEvents',
            withNavigation: component => component
          }));
        const navigation = { navigate: jest.fn() };

        renderer.create(<MyComponent navigation={navigation}/>);
    });
});
```

#### Edit

As requested in comments added `package.json` below:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "^7.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-dynamic-search-bar": "^0.1.11",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^35.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

#### expo-cli version

```
$ expo-cli -V
3.13.1
```

Comment: You probably have some `jest` configuration inside `package.json` that conflicts with mocking  `react-navigation` functions. Can you please share your `package.json` contents? I've tested your code using `RN 0.61` and `react-navigation@4.2.2` and it passes the test without any errors.

Comment: @ChristosLytras Interesting... I've added `package.json`

Comment: You're using Expo which you haven't mention anywhere and that is a very important information. Expo has different behaviour than normal RN projects. Please share your Expo CLI and version you're using. **EDIT** I can see the version in `package.json` and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `jest.mock` has to be outside of `describe` and `it` functions. You don't need to manually mock `navigation` object since you're mocking the `withNavigation` HOC function:

```jsx
// Setup mocks outside describe and it functions
jest.mock('react-navigation', () =>({
  NavigationEvents: 'mockNavigationEvents',
  withNavigation: component => component
}));

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

describe('MyComponent test', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    renderer.create(<MyComponent/>);
  });
});
```

And the `renders` test passes:

[image: Jest test renders]

I suggest you have all those mocks inside a file and set [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfilesafterenv-array) in `package.json`:

#### `package.json` > `jest`:

```
"jest": {
  "preset": "jest-expo"
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["./path/to/jestInit.js"]
},
```

#### `jestInit.js`:

```
jest.mock('react-navigation', () =>({
  NavigationEvents: 'mockNavigationEvents',
  withNavigation: component => component
}));
```

This way, you'll have those mocks for every Jest test file without having to include the mocks inside each test file.

Comment: Arrg! So simple. Thanks very much. Is there a quick answer why it has to be outside `describe`?

Comment: You're welcome. It has to be outside `describe` because at that point, Jest has already loaded the imported files, so it can't override anything.

Comment: I0m getting another issue with this configuration: TypeError: Cannot read property 'light' of undefined